# How to update a table with a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger that reads from table 2 and updates a column in table 1.
I tried with this method but an exception occurred: ORA-04091:table table1 is mutating .

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TRG1"
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 UPDATE table1 SET name =(SELECT name FROM table2
WHERE table1.id = table2.id);
 END;
```

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Why are you duplicating the data across tables? If the name in `table2` is updated then the data in `table1` will be stale - at least until it is updated for some other reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger (as you cannot modify values after they have been inserted or updated) and use the `:NEW` record (rather that trying to update the table and getting into an infinite loop of triggers):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG1
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT name
  INTO   :NEW.name
  FROM   table2
  WHERE  :NEW.id = id;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    :NEW.name := NULL;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yp8KWmUr)

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can only update the name in a before trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TRG1"
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE new_name varchar2(100);
 BEGIN
   
  
       SELECT name INTO new_name FROM table2
        WHERE :new.id = table2.id;
     :new.name :=new_name;   
 END;
/
```

MTO was so nice to make a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8DJeSaBM)

Comment: The syntax in the trigger is invalid as assignment is `:=` and you cannot use a `SELECT` statement in PL/SQL without an `INTO` clause [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5nG_CP-3).

Comment: thank you i corrected my mistake

Comment: @nbk I sincerely appreciate your help.